# MySQL does not listen on port 3306

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL. I can access is locally (and via web phpmyadmin)
But I can't access it from a remote computer.

**Configuration:**

- OS: CentOS7
- MySQL: MySQL Community 8

The port to the service is opened in the firewall. I can verify that via this command.

[image: firewalld]

I also have two users in MySQL (an user with host localhost and an user with host %)[image: mysql_user]

But when I check the port from an nother network. I can't access it

[image: checker]

Did I forgot something? Or did I made mistake? 
Any help will be very appreciated

Comment: Mysql doesn't listen for remote connections by default. You need to do several things before that can happen. Did you edit the my.cnf file to change the bind address?

Comment: I tried both 127.0.0.1 and my external IP - but neither of them are working

Comment: Try ``sudo netstat -tulpn`` on the server and see if the port is actually listening before trying from a remote host.

Comment: When I use 127.0.0.1 as bind IP - 3306 shows up in netstat http://prntscr.com/qooqlf

Comment: You need to use 0.0.0.0 as your bind address

Comment: Are these machines on the same subnet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you would edit the `/etc/my.cnf` (this is the location for CentOS 7) file and make the following changes:

1. Add the line: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`
2. Comment out the line `skip-networking` by placing a `#` in front.

IE:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
# skip-networking
```

The first line defines that this is for the MySql daemon. The second line tells MySql to bind to a network interface, `0.0.0.0` means all interfaces. The third line tells MySql to not skip networking configuration routines.

Note that other distributions may have the MySQL configuration file in different folder locations.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.04, the my.cnf file is under /etc/mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your firewall is open, that is something that can catch you.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

This will verify port 3306 is open on your server and will accept connections to MySQL.

**UPDATE**: I didn't see the part where you had the port open. Cancel this response